Leading Coefficient of Hilbert Polynomial and Multiplicity
Let $R = \mathbb{F}[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ and $I$ be a homogeneous ideal of $R$.
Assume that the leading coefficient of the Hilbert polynomial of $S/I$ is $\frac{a}{d!}$. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_series_and_Hilbert_polynomial). What is the relationship between the multiplicity of $I$ and $a$? I have been unable to find a connection between the Hilbert polynomial and the Hilbert-Samuel function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Samuel_function).
This question arises from a comment in leading coefficient of Hilbert polynomial, where Youngsu mentioned that "the associativity formula for Hilbert-Samuel multiplicity" would be useful in solving this problem. However, I am not familiar with the relationship between them.
